# Why I get such a url when trying to pull a video from YouTube

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Explain why I get such a url. I'm trying to pull a video from YouTube.
Error in console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI 404 (Not Found)
```

Why do I have my localhost first and then a link to the video? How can this be fixed?
index.js:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <video controls>
        <source src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Project folder:
[Project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRz35.png)

Comment: Can you please check your base url in index.js

Comment: Include the protocol - `https://www.youtube...etc`.

Comment: The error has disappeared. Only there is no video anyway, only the player

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/15299500) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using should start with **https://...** and the video is [unavailable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEDEtZ4UVtI), Use another link

For example use this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScMzIvxBSi4
You should use iframe with src of https://www.youtube.com/embed/YourVideoId

currently the ID is **ScMzIvxBSi4** so

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IEDEtZ4UVtI">
```

Replace **YourVideoId** with the video you want
You can also see this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

Comment: @Roman Your video is unavailable so I am using this [placeholder video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScMzIvxBSi4) but you can use any.

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out.  @Ankit Tiwari I would like to ask you one more question if possible.
Is it possible to download videos from a computer in react/next?

Comment: When downloading videos from a computer, I encounter almost the same problem:
    GET http://localhost:3000/pes.mp4 404 (Not Found)
    GET http://localhost:3000/pes.mp4 404 (Not Found)
The pes.mp4 video is at the root of the project.
Path to src="../pes.mp4"

Comment: The video is already on my computer and I would like to show it on my project

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: Your video should be in public folder **public/vis.mp4**